# Laravel pusher error: JSON returned from webapp was invalid, yet status code was 200

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, pusher

i work on laravel 5.2 and i added vinkla/laravel-pusher to do real time chat app on my site but i faced this issue:
"JSON returned from webapp was invalid, yet status code was 200."
this my controller:

```
public function authMessageChat(Request $req)
    {

        $channelName = e($req->input('channel_name'));
        $socketId = e($req->input('socket_id'));
        $auth = $this->pusher->presence_auth($channelName, $socketId, auth()->user()->id);
         return response($auth);

    }
```

this is my script:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}', {
    authEndpoint: '../auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        params: {
            id: currentUser.id
        }
    }
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('{{$chatChannel}}');
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(PusherError){
            console.log('PusherError' + PusherError);
        });
        channel.bind('new-message', function(data) {
        console.log(data.sender);
)};
```

*Pusher error:*
[image: pusher error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your app is returning the debugbar html as part of the json response.

Assuming it's the barryvdh/laravel-debugbar you're using, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar#enablingdisabling-on-run-time) you can switch off the debug bar at runtime:

```
Config::set('laravel-debugbar::config.enabled', false);
```

I assume you'll need to add that prior to the response being sent, in the controller method/route you're using for the authentication endpoint (ie, the one you're calling the [`socket_auth`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#authenticating-private-channels) method from)

Answer (score 1):

@chrismou Thank you for your answer..

your answer is right and we can implement the solution in another way..
just go to your .env file and make:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

instead of

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Thank you